# Codeigniter active record " symbol

Tags: codeigniter

How can I escape " (double quotes) with Codeignniter Acitve Record?

```
$query_string = 'double " quotes';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name WHERE email LIKE "%'.$query_string.'%" ";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

I get mysql error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%" OR email like "%**"**%"

Any suggestions how ti fix that

Comment: Why don't you use methods from the active record class?

`$this->db->where()`
`$this->db->like()`
`$this->db->get()`

Answer (score 2):

You can escape any character by putting a `\` before it.

So `\"`

Comment: it does with its built-in methods, but I guess he's not using those.

Answer (score 1):

Even better, you can bind the parameters!

```
$query_string = '%double " quotes%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name WHERE email LIKE ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($query_string));
```